# React-data-table-component + dropdown cut when open

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-select, react-data-table-component

I am trying to add react-select dropdown with React-data-table-component. But it is cutting the attached screen short.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions for this?

Kamal

Comment: I'd advise to show the code so we can know exactly how are you doing that. Besides that, I'd quickly play with the "z-index" attr of the dropdown to see if you can get it to the front.

Comment: Thank @LaloMores I played with z-index but it is not working :-)